# Why can I connect to MySql with WinSql but not in a connection profile for Eclipse?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse

So I am connecting to a database hosted by my university that I am to use for a project. I want to use Eclipse and OpenJPA to handle the data. However, whenever I try and set up a new connection profile in Eclipse the ping fails. This is odd to me because I can connect to the database on this very computer using WinSql. The following are the details for my connection profile (which are basically identical to what I put in for WinSql):

[image]

Comment: The URL doesn't seem right...

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza How so? I'm not arguing with you because I really don't know. I just know that that was the host I used for WinSql.

Comment: Assumming your server hostname is `cs.iastate.edu`, then the URL should be: `jdbc:mysql://cs.iastate.edu:3306/` where `3306` is the port to communicate to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my problem. @LuiggiMedoza was correct. The URL was wrong. I had to switch it to jdbc:mysql:mysql.cd.iastate.edy:3306/db309T11